# Craftsman 139.55918 garage door opener won’t close

Tags: garage

The door sensors each have a green light that is on. They do not change state if an object is placed between them. I get a code from the opener. 1 up and 4 down on the indicator arrows. This code indicates an obstruction between the sensors. I have the same opener on my other door and when I place an object between the sensors one of the lights goes out. This doesn’t happen on the opener that won’t close. I have 6 volts dc at the opener sensor terminals.

I haven’t connected the known good sensors. Nothing has changed. If I intentionally misalign the sensors both stay green on the door that won’t close. On the door that works if I obstruct or misalign the sensors the green light on the sensor with the black striped wire goes out.

Comment: Note that both your question post and comments have an Edit button.

Comment: Well, disconnect the good sensors at their unit and run jumpers over to the faulty unit. Whether that resolves the issue tells you whether the problem is in a sensor or the unit.

Comment: If both sensors stay green when they are misaligned, the problem is probably in the control board (inside the motor?).

Comment: I’m going to try numbering from the good one. Thanks

Comment: I meant jumper from the good one. I’ll post back tomorrow.